# mongoengine filter query retrieve embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

```
import mongoengine

class MyLog(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    text = mongoengine.StringField()

class Server(mongoengine.DynamicDocument):
    name = mongoengine.StringField()
    status = mongoengine.StringField()
    text_list = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(MyLog))
```

`Server.objects.all()` queryset doesn't include `text_list` field's value by default.
I've to do this- (to get `text_list` field's value for each object in queryset.

```
for s in Server.objects.all():
    print s.text_list
```

In my case/scenario, I can't do this, I mean I have to get all data in a queryset itself(or in other words, I need to have a queryset which will give me the all nested details as well without using `obj.text_list`)

for e.g.

Further in mongo shell -
`db.server.find()` includes all the nested embedded documents.

```
{ 
  '_id': ObjectId("272742942qbe5451b4f4b9e7"),
  'name':'nm',
  'status': 'st',
  'text_list': [
       {# here it's including embedded model's info too, no need to make extra query, looking for similar query in mongoengine orm
         'text': 'done'
      }
  ]
}
```

how can we do this in mongoengine using orm or raw_query.

I can solve this problem in mongoengine orm by using `to_json()` method

`json.loads(queryset.to_json())`

`Server.objects.all().to_json()`  returns a result which include embedded models's info but this is not efficient when using pagination on millions documents, I mean in that case mongo will try to convert all objects to to_json.

Comment: please clarify the question. first you say that the result is not included then you say that you can access the result through an instance attribute.

Comment: @lesingerouge: updated question details.

Comment: Like @lesingerouge says, it is unclear what you want. The queryset does return the document with its embedded fields you can access as instance attributes. What else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paginate the results of your queryset using flask-mongoengine, you should simply use the `paginate` method of the `Queryset`:

```
# Paginate through todo
def view_todos(page=1):
    paginated_todos = Todo.objects.paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
```

[Here](https://flask-mongoengine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can find more info about the templating part and other functions available.